# I am trying to take input from an excel column to a list but in the column data there value like "T500 and 7500C"

Tags: c#, excel

I am using OLEDB connection in c# to take input data from an excel sheet to a list  but while extracting there are some values in the column as follows "400T,500c, V4450, 4500, 5000". Integers can be extracted successfully but the other values takes null in the list.
So how to take those values containing integer+variable(4500c) into the list??

```
List<string> datalist= new List<string>();
using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())

                {
                    if (counter > 0)
                    {

                        datalist.Add(dr[0].ToString());

                    }
                    counter++;
                }
}
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are asking? Could you edit your question to make it clearer what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is caused by mixed types. In some columns you have integers but in other you have text. Try setting format of column in excel to Text or add "IMEX=1;" to your connection string.